# SyntaxError: Unexpected token \n in JSON at position

Tags: json, cloudflare-workers

I have a roblem while directing a request from Cloud Flare workers to my API. When I catch the error I get this:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token \n in JSON at position 240`

when I did some research I saw some articles about it being about JSON.parse. But I couldn't find the solution.

**Example Request Body**:

```
{"link": "link", "provider": "company", "oauth": "key", "testText": "text"}
```

**Cloud Flare Workers Code**:

```
addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
const { request } = event;
const response = handleRequest(request).catch(handleError)
event.respondWith(response)
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
const realBody = JSON.parse(`${await request.json()}`
            .replace(/\n/g, "\\n")
            .replace(/\r/g, "\\r")
            .replace(/\t/g, "\\t")
            .replace(/\f/g, "\\f"));
const stringifiedJSON = JSON.stringify(realBody);
const init = {
  body: stringifiedJSON,
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  },
};
const initLog = {
  body: JSON.stringify({ msg: { discountBodyStringified: realBody }}),
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  },
}

const responseLogger = await fetch("https://example.com/log", initLog)
console.log(responseLogger)
console.log(init)
const response = await fetch("https://example.com", init)
return new Response("tweet sent!")
}

  function handleError(error) {
  console.error('Uncaught error:', error)

  const { stack } = error
  const initLog = {
  body: JSON.stringify({ msg: { error: stack || error }}),
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  },
}

const responseLogger = fetch("https://example.com/log", initLog)
return new Response(stack || error, {
status: 500,
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'
}
})
}
```

Comment: noob question here since I just started using fetch, but why are you parsing and then stringifying again the `request`? isn't the result of `request.json()` already a js object (after fulfilling the promise)? can't it be stringified directly?

Comment: so when I tried to do it without the parse it didn't work idk why but i'll give it a shot again

Comment: it didnt work :/

Comment: damn, I don't know then, I'm as lost as you ahah, are you totally sure about the content of `request`? What happens if you console.log() it before and after using .json() ?

Answer (score 1):

problem is not in the code, the problem in request which you are or front app is sending somewhere you lived extra comma or didnt close field.
For example:

{
"name": "Alice",
}

this will give same error as SyntaxError: Unexpected token \n in JSON at position because extra comma is there or

{
"name": "Alice
}

this also will throw error because I didnt close quotes